# FromBody in WebService

Tags: c#, web-services

I am making WebService(.asmx) and I want to use some kind of attribute like  [FromBody] in WebApi. For example I have web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public virtual ServiceResponse GetTest(Test request){}
```

but when i send the request in json it looks like that:

```
{
  "request":
  {
  "parameter1" : "param1",
  "parameter2" : "param12",
  }
}
```

I want the json request to be without "request".But when i remove it i get exception: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'request'.
 How can I achieve that in Web Services?

Comment: Oh wait I understand your question now.  You would be better off using `[WebInfoke(Method="POST", ...` then it will load the object directly in the body.

Comment: Thank you for the response but it didn't work

Comment: Do you send it as `{"parameter1":"param1","parameter2":"param2"}` or how are you sending it?

Comment: I want to send it like your comment without "request", but it keeps throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I was able to do what you are trying to do:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "save")]
public BaseResponse SaveSurvey(Survey survey) { ... }
```

It then reads in the data as `Content-Type: application/json` in the form

```
{
  guid: #,
  name: "",
  ... 
}
```